# How to update a table with null values with data from other table at one time?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have 2 tables - A and B . Table A has two columns, `pkey` (primary key) and `col1`. Table B also has two columns, `pr_key` (primary key but not a foreign key) and `column1`.  Both tables have 4 rows.  Table B has no values in `column1`, while table A has `column1` values for all 4 rows.  So my data looks like this

```
Table A 
pkey col1 
A    10 
B    20  
C    30 
D    40 

Table B 
pr_key column1 
A      null 
B      null 
C      null 
D      null
```

I want to update table B to set the `column1` value of each row equal to the `column1` value of the equivalent row from table A in a single DML statement.

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like that (depends on SQL implementation you use, but in general, the following is rather standard. In particular should work in MS-SQL and in MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO tblB (pr_key, column1)
  SELECT pkey, col1
  FROM tblA
  -- WHERE some condition (if you don't want 100% of A to be copied)
```

The question is a bit unclear as to the nature of tblB's pr_key, if for some reason this was a default/auto-incremented key for that table, it could just then be omitted from both the column list (in parenthesis) and in the SELECT that follows.  In this fashion upon insertion of each new row, a new value would be generated.

**Edit**: It appears the OP actually wants to update table B with values from A.
The syntax for this should then be something like

```
UPDATE tblB 
SET Column1 = A.Col1
FROM tblA AS A
JOIN tblB AS B ON B.pr_key = A.pkey
```

Comment: Ok,I am sorry.Since pr_key of table B is a primary key,so null values cannot be inserted in table B.Hence the values for pr_key is same as pkey column of Table A.Table A has been arbitrarily populated with 4 rows.

Comment: Table A

pkey   col1

A         10
B          20   
C          30
D         40


Table B

pr_key  column1

A          null
B           null
C         null
D        null

I want to updaet table B with col1 of table A at one go.

Comment: @Anupam Ray, check the edit where I added UPDATE syntax.  (Not 100% sure this is ok with Oracle 10g [now that you specified it], but again, should be damn close, check Oracle's docs)

Comment: +1 - The `UPDATE` syntax isn't valid for Oracle, though.  You need a subquery to get the correlated update to work.

Answer (score 1):

This may perform better:

```
MERGE INTO tableB
USING (select pkey, col1 from tableA) a
ON (tableB.pr_key = a.pkey)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET tableB.column1 = a.col1;
```

Comment: This is tagged for 10g.  Didn't 10g require that a `MERGE` statement have a `WHEN NOT MATCHED` section?  I thought it was only 11g that made that optional

Comment: No, it's optional in 10g as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do a correlated update.  The syntax for that in Oracle is

```
UPDATE tableB b
   SET column1 = (SELECT a.column1
                    FROM tableA a
                   WHERE a.pkey = b.pr_key)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM tableA a
                WHERE a.pkey = b.pr_key )
```

The `WHERE EXISTS` clause isn't necessary if `tableA` and `tableB` each have 4 rows and have the same set of keys in each.  It is much safer to include that option, though, to avoid updating `column1` values of `tableB` to `NULL` if there is no matching row in `tableA`.